# rviz2 not loading "Entry Point Not Found"(Windows)

Tags: rviz, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if this is a simple error... getting back into ROS after being away for 7 years or so.  Maybe I need to setup a PC with Ubuntu again.. but thought I'd try with Windows 10 first.

I've followed the install steps for everything listed in the [ros installation guide page](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html#environment-setup), I've installed chocolaty and ROS Foxy using the Windows(alternate install method)

Everything seems to install fine, I can run the Talker and Listener, Turtle Sim Example, but RViz2 isn't working.

I get two "Entry Point Not Found" errors, both .dll's are located in the directories shown in the erros.

Error1:

"
The procedure entry point
?hasEdgeList@MovableObject@Ogre@@UEAA_NXZ could not
be located in the dynamic link library
C:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\bin\rviz_common.dll.
"

Error 2:

"
The procedure entry point
?coulour@ManualObject@Ogre@@UEAAXAEBVColourValue@2@@Z could not
be located in the dynamic link library
C:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\bin\rviz_rendering.dll.
"

I've tried setting my paths as I've seen in another [ROSAnswers forum post](https://answers.ros.org/question/347881/ros2-on-windows-entry-point-not-found/)

Using that post I tried running my workspace setup with an admin CMD window thinking maybe it could fix a path issue.

Below is what I used as my workspace setup, but it didn't change any issues since I think they were pointing to the correct location already.

---

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -arch=amd64 -host_arch=amd64

SET Qt5_DIR=C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64

SET QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\plugins\platforms

SET "ChocolateyInstall=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey"

SET "PATH=C:\python38; C:\python38\scripts; C:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\bin; C:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib;%PATH%"

SET "PYTHONHOME=c:\Python38"

SET "PYTHONPATH=c:\Python38\lib\site-packages;c:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\lib\site-packages"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397133/rviz2-not-loading-%22entry-point-not-found%22(windows)/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2022-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2022-05-25**:
@ncr7 did you resolve this? I'm having similar startup issues with rviz2.

**Comment by [marpeja](https://answers.ros.org/users/101482/marpeja/) on 2022-06-02**:
I am having the same issue, but never happened to me before...

**Comment by [marpeja](https://answers.ros.org/users/101482/marpeja/) on 2022-07-28**:
Did anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, was having the same problem, the command "ros2 run rviz2 rviz2" works for me. Try checking it out.

---

Originally posted by [joez85](https://answers.ros.org/users/108506/joez85/) with karma: 26 on 2022-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2022-08-30**:
Been away a while... ended up loading Ubuntu :)
Your solution worked for me.